# Get a collection from Firestore in Unity?

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to get a firestore collection in Unity by following [this link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data?hl=es#get_all_documents_in_a_collection), but it gives me an error:

> 'Task' does not contain a definition for 'Documents' and no accessible extension method 'Documents' accepting a first argument of type 'Task'.

**My Code:**

```
CollectionReference allCitiesQuery = db.Collection("MyList");
Task<QuerySnapshot> allCitiesQuerySnapshot = allCitiesQuery.GetSnapshotAsync();

foreach (DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot in allCitiesQuerySnapshot.Documents)
      {           
          Dictionary<string, object> city = documentSnapshot.ToDictionary();
          foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> pair in city)
          {
            Debug.Log(pair.Key + " " + pair.Value);
            //Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", pair.Key, pair.Value);
          }
      }
    }
```

I have read the documentation but there is very little focus on Unity because a few days ago it was just implemented. Can anyone help me here, please?

Answer (score 4):

Try changing

```
CollectionReference allCitiesQuery = db.Collection("MyList");
Task<QuerySnapshot> allCitiesQuerySnapshot = allCitiesQuery.GetSnapshotAsync();
```

into

```
Query allCitiesQuery = db.Collection("MyList");
QuerySnapshot allCitiesQuerySnapshot = await allCitiesQuery.GetSnapshotAsync();
```

and ensure you have all the following included:

```
using Firebase;
using Firebase.Firestore;
using Firebase.Extensions;
```

Comment: This is correct, generally you have a Task and have to get the task.Result out when task.IsComplete. Async/await isn't the only way to do this though (and isn't always the best). I break it down here: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2019/07/firebase-and-tasks-how-to-deal-with.html, but basically your other options are to use ContinueWithOnMainThread or literally wait (usually with WaitUntil in a coroutine) for IsComplete to go to true and pull out Result.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! Philipp I implemented the "await" again and I read [this](https://contentful.github.io/contentful.net-docs/articles/async-programming.html)  reference, now it works. I leave the code inside a response in case some other user needs it.

Comment: Pux0r3, I will definitely read it later because I want to improve my code, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the functional code for those who have a related problem.

```
using Firebase;
using Firebase.Extensions;
using Firebase.Firestore;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class Example  : MonoBehaviour
{

public  async void GetMyCollections()
    {
      Query allCitiesQuery = db.Collection("MyRootCollection");
      QuerySnapshot allCitiesQuerySnapshot = await allCitiesQuery.GetSnapshotAsync();

      foreach (DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot in allCitiesQuerySnapshot.Documents)
      {
          Dictionary<string, object> city = documentSnapshot.ToDictionary();
          foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> pair in city)
          {
            Debug.Log(pair.Key + " " + pair.Value);
          }
      }
    }
}
```

References: [FirebaseDocs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data?hl=es#get_all_documents_in_a_collection), [Async programming](https://contentful.github.io/contentful.net-docs/articles/async-programming.html).